# Methods to find n+1 queries in a rails app views?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I use both [find_by_sql](https://www.sqlbot.co/blog/rails-find_by_sql-make-your-page-load-35-times-faster) and joins to get rid of n+1 queries in my Rails apps and make page loads faster, but often I forget to do this until things get slow in production environments.   The [bullet gem](https://github.com/flyerhzm/bullet) can find these, but do any other ways exist besides that gem and just looking at logs?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found a easy way to to this on Heroku, just use [Scoutapp](https://scoutapp.com/)'s free add-on.